# what does 'would' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Baring the teeth in a hostile way, as noted by Charles Darwin in the nineteenth century, may be a universal sign of anger. As the originator of the theory of evolution, Darwin believed that the universal recognition of facial expressions **would** have survival value. For example, facial expressions could signal the approach of enemies (or friends) in the absence of language.

Comment: I ***would*** think auxiliary verb "would" doesn't really mean anything in either the cited example or this very sentence in my comment. Arguably it carries slight overtones of "hesitancy", as in ***If** I were to think about this* in my example, or ***If** evolutionists were to gather more evidence regarding Darwin's suppositions*. But imho the example cited above means *exactly* the same with or without the auxiliary verb.

Comment: Have you checked a good bilingual English>Chinese dictionary?? I will have my new car tomorrow. She said she would have her new car tomorrow.

Comment: ...actually, ***would*** isn't "inflected for number", but since the "syntactic subject" of the verb is singular *[universal] **recognition***, if we remove the auxiliary we have to inflect the remaining verb: *Darwin believed that the universal recognition of facial expressions **has / had** survival value* (it's a stylistic choice whether to "backshift" ***has*** to ***had*** here). This is important, because Darwin isn't directly referring to the facial expressions themselves here - he's talking about the ability to ***recognise*** them.

Comment: ...I think it's in the movie *Platoon (1986)* that we see a culture clash between American GI's who think baring teeth displays ***contemptuous amusement***, where actually the grinning Vietnamese victim is displaying ***abject terror***.

Comment: ...actually, would isn't "inflected for number" means 'would' isn't inflected for 'tense', right?